# How to calculate F-measure with only Positive Data

Tags: classification, biostatistics, accuracy

I'm new in statistics and I have a question about finding f-measure once we do not have any "negative" data.
I have a list of items with confidence score (between 0 and 1) calculated for each item:

`ItemList = {A1, A2, ..., An}`

`ConfidenceScore = {CS1, CS2, ..., CSn}`

and a Gold-standard which I believe they are correct:

`Gold-Standard = {A2, A10, ..., Am}`

`Gold-Standard_ConfidenceScore = {CS2, CS10, ..., CSm}`

where `Gold-Standard` is a subset of `ItemList`

I want to put a threshold for the confidence scores (e.g. 0.5). How to find the **best threshold** while my gold-standard includes *only* positive data? Any paper/hint?

Thanks.